# Error after updating Spring Boot version from 2.2.X to 2.6.4

Tags: java, spring-boot, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my Spring Boot application from 2.2.X to 2.6.4. While running my application I am getting below error,

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.Bootstrapper
at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[?:?]
```

I tried but was not able fix for this.

Comment: `Bootstrapper` was removed in Spring Boot 2.6. Check your other dependencies (Spring Cloud, perhaps) and check that they are compatible with 2.6.